# Add two 4-D arrays in Python

Tags: python, beginner, performance, array

I have two arrays, each with shape (1, 51, 150, 207)

I need to add them such that:

```
newarray[0][0][0][0] = array1[0][0][0][0] + array2[0][0][0][0]
newarray[0][0][0][1] = array1[0][0][0][1] + array2[0][0][0][1]
```

for every element in the array.

Currently I'm creating a new array using nested while loops but this approach is extremely time consuming. Can anyone offer a better solution?

```
H = 0
NS = 0
EW = 0
height = []
while H < 51:
    northsouth = []
    while NS < 150:
        eastwest = []
        while EW < 207:
            eastwest.append(PH[0][H][NS][EW] + PHB[0][H][NS][EW])
            EW += 1
            print eastwest
        northsouth.append(eastwest)
        NS += 1
        print northsouth
    height.append(northsouth)
    H =+ 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Arrays can definitely be tricky to work with, but I'm sure our Python pros will have some good advice for you!

Comment: How does this work? Have you tested it?

Comment: So it starts by adding the [0][0][0][0] elements in the two arrays and appending them to a blank array. Once it goes through every element in the 4th position it increments up to [0][0][1][0] and does the same thing all the way through each index.

Comment: The very last line, `H =+ 1`, shouldn't it be `H += 1` ?

Comment: Why aren't you using `numpy`, in which this would be `newarray = array1 + array2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, code that looks like:

```
foo = 0
while foo < bar:
    ...  # foo doesn't change here
    foo += 1
```

is a bad sign. In Python, this can immediately be simplified, using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range), to:

```
for foo in range(bar):
    ...
```

---

Secondly, hard-coding the shape of your "arrays" everywhere (having the literals `51`, `150` and `207` in the code itself), referred to as *"magic numbers"*, is poor practice in every programming language. These are the lengths of each sub-list, so should be calculated as needed using `len(...)`. This makes the code more flexible; it can now be easily applied to add arrays of other sizes. it's also slightly awkward to hard-code the *depth* of the addition (i.e. that it only handles four-dimensional arrays).

---

Thirdly, however, code like:

```
for index in range(len(sequence)):
    element = sequence[index]
    ...
```

is generally better replaced with:

```
for element in sequence:
    ...
```

where you need the index too, you can use `enumerate`, and where you need to iterate over multiple iterables you can use `zip`; Python has lots of handy functions for dealing with iterables (see also `itertools`).

---

Fourthly, when you have a loop `append`ing to a list, it's usually more efficient to replace it with a [*"list comprehension"*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). For example:

```
foo = []
for bar in baz:
    foo.append(bar)
```

can be replaced by:

```
foo = [bar for bar in baz]
```

---

Finally, however, this is totally trivial if you switch to `numpy`, which is extremely helpful for manipulating arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, (1, 51, 150, 207))
>>> arr2 = np.random.randint(1, 10, (1, 51, 150, 207))
>>> arr1 + arr2  # wasn't that easy!
array([[[[11, 13, 14, ...,  9, 14,  8],
         [15,  4, 10, ..., 14, 10, 16],
         [11, 11,  9, ...,  4,  9,  9],
         ..., 
         [17, 10, 14, ..., 10, 12, 12],
         [12, 11, 14, ...,  7,  8,  8],
         [ 9, 11,  6, ...,  3, 11,  8]],

        [[10, 15, 16, ..., 11, 16, 10],
         [17, 17,  8, ...,  8,  7,  8],
         [11,  7,  2, ..., 16, 11,  5],
         ..., 
         [15, 10, 16, ..., 16, 13,  9],
         [15,  8,  7, ..., 13,  5,  6],
         [ 4,  5, 10, ...,  7, 10, 10]],

        [[11, 10,  4, ..., 10,  7, 11],
         [12,  3, 14, ..., 11, 12, 12],
         [ 6, 11, 16, ..., 14,  9, 12],
         ..., 
         [18, 10, 11, ..., 13, 14,  9],
         [11, 11, 10, ...,  9, 13, 12],
         [10, 10, 10, ..., 12, 14,  8]],

        ..., 
        [[16, 11, 12, ..., 13, 13,  9],
         [ 7, 15, 10, ...,  9, 11,  5],
         [ 5, 11, 14, ..., 14,  4, 11],
         ..., 
         [15, 13,  6, ..., 17,  6, 10],
         [ 9, 12,  7, ...,  7, 17, 11],
         [12,  9, 10, ...,  4,  9,  5]],

        [[15, 12, 10, ...,  5, 12, 15],
         [17, 14, 15, ..., 13, 11,  8],
         [13, 10, 10, ...,  8,  4,  8],
         ..., 
         [12,  9, 10, ...,  9,  7, 12],
         [13, 12, 17, ...,  7, 13, 10],
         [13,  6,  8, ..., 15, 13,  7]],

        [[ 9,  8,  8, ...,  6, 10,  2],
         [ 9, 15, 14, ..., 14,  4,  5],
         [ 3, 12, 12, ...,  5, 10, 14],
         ..., 
         [ 6, 11, 15, ..., 11,  4, 15],
         [ 4, 12, 14, ..., 12, 11,  9],
         [10,  3,  5, ...,  5,  7, 10]]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can always recommend is to move redundant code into the outermost scope possible.   When you are calling `PH[0][H][NS][EW]`, you might as well be doing this:

*note: This code is **not** analogous to yours, it's simply for demonstration purposes*

```
while H < 51
    while NS < 150
        while EW < 207
            # everything below is executed 1,583,550 times (51*150*207)
            root_array = PH[0]   # 1.5 million times for this one
            H_array = root_array[H] # 1.5 million times for this one too
            NS_array = H_array[NS]  # now we're at over 4.5 million evaluations
            # the previous 3 evaluations are unnecessary in this scope

            EW_value = NS_array[EW]
            # NOW do something with EW_value
```

The core loop (`while EW < 207`) does not need to re-evaluate all of those array expressions.  By moving the values to the outermost scope possible, you minimize inefficient redundancy.

**Suggestion:**

```
root_array = PH[0]                   # PH[0] is now only evaluated once
while H < 51
    H_array = root_array[H]          # only evaluated 51 times (saves 1,583,499 cycles)
    while NS < 150
        NS_array = H_array[NS]       # evaluated 7,650 times (saves 1,575,900 cycles)
        while EW < 207
            EW_value = NS_array[EW]
            # do something with EW_value
```

Using this method we have prevented the unnecessary execution of 4,742,949 reads